# How to check if the device if registered with GCM because official tutorial states "regID is not guaranteed to last indefinitely"

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I know this question has been asked few times already, but I haven't found satisfying answer because one   part of text in Google's tutorial for GCM bugs me:

> A given regID is not guaranteed to last indefinitely, so the first thing your app should always do is check to make sure it has a valid regID (as shown in the code snippets above)

I am saving returned ID and application version in table on device and every time in launcher activity application check for ID and registers device if ID does not exists.

But, how do they mean "regID is not guaranteed to last indefinitely". How can device know if it has lost its regID on GCM server if it checks for it locally only in Shared preferences or in Table?

Comment: From the device,You can't check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through [code](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html), It seems Google only wants us to re-register on App updates.

```
private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
   final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
   String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
   if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
      return "";
   }
   // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
   // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
   // app version.
   int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
   int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
   if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
     Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
     return "";
   }
   return registrationId;
}
```

[**GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId**](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.java) also does the same thing. Which is now [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html).

```
public static String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    // check if app was updated; if so, it must clear registration id to
    // avoid a race condition if GCM sends a message
    int oldVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int newVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (oldVersion != Integer.MIN_VALUE && oldVersion != newVersion) {
        Log.v(TAG, "App version changed from " + oldVersion + " to " +
                newVersion + "; resetting registration id");
        clearRegistrationId(context);
        registrationId = "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}
```

**EDIT**

Going through the documentation and code (at-least) I could not find any other way for client to know if it needs to re-register. However, you can get some server error responses when trying to send notification to expired or a duplicated registration ID. If the registration ID has expired the app server can ask the client to re-register and if it is [duplicate](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#canonical) app sever should replace the existing reg id with *canonical_id* which Google returns.

Please read this [link](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#error_codes) for more details on how interpret those error messages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that part is ok, I've already implemented that. Matter of fact I've implemented everything and push notifications work like a charm. That sentence I've quoted bugs me, that given regID is not guaranteed to last indefinitely... How can I know if given regID is not valid any more? Does Google guaranties that given regID for particular device will persist on GCM until device reregister or  unregister?

Comment: @Munez Well I understand your frustration, but going through the documentation and code I could not find any other way for client to know if it needs to re-register. However, you can get some server error responses when trying to send notification to expired or a duplicated registration ID.

Answer (score -1):

I have placed a code snippet at Splash screen which checks for the regId from Google server and based on the results we proceed accordingly. If the regId is null, we create a new one. And if it returns a valid regId we check this Id against the one saved in our preferences. In case of any change we update the Id in our preferences as well as to our servers.

```
/**
 * Method is used to get/check regId for Google cloud messaging.
 * 
 * @param context
 *         - Context of the class from where it is called.
 *         
 * @return void
 */
public static String myRegistrationId(Context context) {

    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
    context.registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(GCMUtilities.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
    // this line of code checks if there exists a valid regId for this
    // device otherwise it will return null value.
    String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context); 
    System.out.println("My registeration id is " + regId);

    //if null value is returned we will create a new regId
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Registering app on start up");
        GCMRegistrar.register(context, GCMUtilities.GCM_APP_KEY);
        System.out.println("Registering done");
        regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
        System.out.println("My registeration id is " + regId);
        //Utilities.showDLog("~~~~~~~" +"" +"" +"~~~~~~~", "=====regId=====" + regId);
    }
    else{ //returns a valid regId
        /**
         * Compare this regId against our existing RegId stored in preferences and in
         * case of any change update it to our server as well as update preferences.
         */

        // here goes the code to update preferences 
        // and also update the new Id at the server
    }

    /*
     * Save GCM registration id 
     */
    Constants.GCM_DEVICE_TOKEN = regId;
    return regId;
}
```