# How to know if my app has an instance id/is registered with GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I need to know if i have an instance id when my user logs in to the app in a deterministic manner. Is there any other way to know other than *trying* to get an instance id and handling the possible exception? - That approach is prone to failing because the documentation only mentions an IOException, which might be raised because of a network exception or some other IO error.

I am tracking the value myself with SharedPreferences but that seems a bit fickle as the app may not be used for a bit of time and the value might get out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

An Android application running on a mobile device registers to receive messages by calling the Google Cloud Messaging method register. This method registers the application for GCM and returns he registration ID.

Based from this [Demo App](https://github.com/google/gcm), they refresh the registration ID by setting an expiration date on the value persisted locally by app. they load their locally stored regstration id. If it is `expired` they call `gcm.register()`.

This doesn't handle the hypothetical scenario in which a registration ID is refreshed by Google for an app that hasn't been launched for a long time.

Your app can request tokens from the Instance ID service as needed using the `getToken()` method, and like `InstanceID`, your app can also store tokens on your own server. All tokens issued to your app belong to the app's InstanceID.

Tokens are unique and secure, but your app or the Instance ID service may need to refresh tokens in the event of a security issue or when a user uninstalls and reinstalls your app during device restoration. Your app must implement a listener to respond to token refresh requests from the Instance ID service.

You may check this documentation of how to do proper implementation:

- https://developers.google.com/instance-id/
- https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation

Here's a related SO ticket, discuss how to check if the device is registered:

- [How to check if the device if registered with GCM because official tutorial states "regID is not guaranteed to last indefinitely"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057925/how-to-check-if-the-device-if-registered-with-gcm-because-official-tutorial-stat)
- [Google Cloud Messaging - Check if device is already registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580622/google-cloud-messaging-check-if-device-is-already-registered)

Answer (score 0):

When using InstanceID you call getToken to retrieve the token from local cache (in Google Play services) if it already exists or make a network call to retrieve a new token. So if your app already has a token then a call to getToken should return immediately since it is a local call. If you get an IOException then that is a clear signal that your app does not currently have a token.

Another option that you should consider is using the new FCM client library. It handles the token requesting and refreshing for you, so all you need is a call to [`FirebaseInstanceId.getToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#public-methods) which will return a token if one exists or null if one does not.